# Finding the asymptotes of the polar curve $ r=\frac{ 5\cos^2 \theta+3 }{ 5\cos^2 \theta-1 }$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, curves

Find all asymptotes ( their equations in polar or cartesian form) for the polar curve

$$ r(\theta)=\dfrac{ 5\cos^2 \theta+3 }{ 5\cos^2 \theta-1 }$$

When denominator goes to zero we have one set, but what is the other set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four asymptotes. After converting to cartesian form they can be factored and expressed as:

$$ \pm 2 x +y = \pm \sqrt{5} $$

There are two parallel asymptote pairs.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are right, values are given by

$$5\cos^2 \theta-1=0 \implies \cos \theta = \pm\frac1{\sqrt 5}\implies \theta_{1,2}=\pm \arccos \left(\frac1{\sqrt 5}\right),\: \theta_{3,4}=\pm \arccos \left(-\frac1{\sqrt 5}\right)$$

To find the asymptotes equations let consider for any direction $\theta_0$ (wlog assume $ \theta_0=\theta_{1}$)

$$y=\tan \theta_0 \, x+q \iff q=r\cos \theta (\tan \theta-\tan \theta_0)$$

then

$$q=\lim_{\theta\to \theta_0} (5\cos^2 \theta+3)\cos\theta \frac{\tan \theta-\tan \theta_0}{5\cos^2 \theta-1}=\sqrt 5$$

indeed

$$ (5\cos^2 \theta+3)\cos(\theta)\to \frac4{\sqrt 5}$$

and by l’Hopital

$$q=\lim_{\theta\to \theta_0}\frac{\tan \theta-\tan \theta_0}{5\cos^2 \theta-1}= \lim_{\theta\to \theta_0}-\frac{1}{10\cos^3\theta\sin \theta}=\frac 54$$

Comment: There are four asymptotes in this answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: So equations are  $y=\pm 2x\;?$

Comment: Yes exactly in cartesian. In polar coordinates $\theta=\theta{_0}$ are indeed rays through the origin.

Comment: Exactly in cartesian ?

Comment: Yes these are the equations!

Comment: The asymptote rays are not through the origin.

Comment: @Narasimham I see now your answer, let me check that. Thanks!

Comment: @Narasimham I obtain this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator). An  asymptote not through the origin would have an equation in the form $r=r(\theta)$ and not $\theta=\theta_0$.

Comment: Somehow, I cannot access desmos. Can you please send the graph as answer or comment in the answer box? The given polar coordinate function is in the form $r=r(\theta).$

Comment: Oh now I get your point! It’s an interesting case. Now I’m busy but I’ll take a closer look later on that.

Comment: I get it! I’m going to add the details asap.